# Conditionally add properties to elements of array with yq (version 4)

Tags: arrays, yaml, jq, yq

I have a YAML document that contains an array. I would like to conditionally add properties to the elements of that array using [`yq` version 4](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v4.x/upgrading-from-v3) from mikefarah.

Here is a sample YAML document.

```
name: "My Pets"
pets:
- name: "cat"
  age: 8
- name: "dog"
  age: 3
- name: "mouse"
  age: 1
```

I would like to transform this into,

```
name: "My Pets"
pets:
- name: "cat"
  age: 8
  shots: cat.upToDate
- name: "dog"
  age: 3
  shots: dog.upToDate
- name: "mouse"
  age: 1
  shots: mouse.upToDate
```

where we add a `shots` property to each element of `pets`. The value of `shots` should be whatever the `name` value is, dot, `upToDate`.

I'm trying something like this,

```
yq eval '.pets[] | select(.name == "cat").shots = "cat.upToDate"' test.yaml
```

but that produces,

```
name: "cat"
age: 8
shots: cat.upToDate
name: "dog"
age: 3
name: "mouse"
age: 1
```

I need to preserve the entire original YAML document and just insert the `shots` property.

This is close but missing all of the other pets.

```
yq eval '.pets = (.pets[] | select(.name == "cat").shots = "cats.upToDate")' test.yaml
```

It produces,

```
name: "My Pets"
pets:
  name: "cat"
  age: 8
  shots: cats.upToDate
```

I'm thinking maybe we could store the name of the pet in a variable and reference that later, but v4 is brand new to me today.

I would prefer to have a one-liner so that I don't have to filter on `.name`. This array has less than 10 elements so I could easily hard-code the name and call `yq` 10 times.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Many thanks, Weldon

Comment: This is really close. If `cat` could be dynamically computed this would work: `yq eval '.pets = (.pets | .[].shots = "cat.upToDate")' test.yaml`

Comment: This is even closer, but it's repeating `cat` for each `shots` value: `yq eval '.pets = (.pets | .[].shots = .[].name + ".upToDate")' test.yaml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `|=`, e.g. like so:

```
yq eval '.pets[] |= (.shots = (.name + ".upToDate"))' pets.yaml
```

Comment: Ah I see. That works perfectly. I overlooked the [update](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update) section of the docs.